# iOS - my app keeps asking for sandboxed user to login

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I created a sandboxed user.  Signed out of app store on my device, and used my test user to make a test purchase.  All good.

Now I signed back into my real account.  Every time I open the app, it asks for my test user's credentials immediately.

I tried deleting my test user.  I tried deleting the app.  I tried signing out of app store.  It's STILL asking for this test user's credentials on every app launch on my device.  How do I start fresh?

here is my code, although I'm not sure it's really related to my issue

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // storekit delegation
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    self.getProductInfo()
}

func getProductInfo(){
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(object: self.productID))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
//        else {
//            please enable in app purchases
//        }
    }
```

**Delegate methods**

```
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    var products = response.products

    if products.count != 0 {
        self.product = products[0] as? SKProduct
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    if queue.transactions.count != 0 {
        if let purchase = queue.transactions[0] as? SKPaymentTransaction {
            if purchase.payment.productIdentifier == self.productID {
                println("you bought it already")
            }
        }
    } 
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction in transactions as [SKPaymentTransaction] {

        switch transaction.transactionState {

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
//                self.unlockFeature()
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same problem now.

Comment: Oh man this was so long ago I really can't remember :/. I did finish my game so I must've figured something out

Comment: This is killing me.  I have two devices with two different test users that keep popping up, and I no longer have those users active in itunes connect.  The real kicker is that I tried to recreate them just so I could close this out, and itunes won't let me, because it says they already exist...awesome.  This effectively kills my ability to test the in app purchases for this app now.

Comment: Maybe try calling Apple dev support. 99% of the time they're useless but you never know

Comment: Truer words were never spoken.  Thanks anyway!